# factorial moment and falling factorial

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a function for a [factorial moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment)

`E(x_{r}) = x! / (x - r)!`

But the program below takes a large time if an element in the array ar is large. Can anyone help me to make the program more efficient?

```
 def fact_mom(ar, order):
    sum = 0.0
    for ix in ar:
        if ix != 0:
           a = math.factorial(ix) / math.factorial(ix - order)
           sum += a
    return sum / len(tt)
```

Comment: unable to reproduce your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pre-calculate the factorials instead of calculating them each time.

```
def fact_mom(ar, order):
    factorial = [1] * MAX_VAL
    for i in range(1, MAX_VAL):
        factorial[i] = factorial[i - 1] * i

    sum = 0.0
    for ix in ar:
        if ix != 0:
           a = factorial[ix] / factorial[ix - order]
           sum += a
    return sum / len(tt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to multiply elements in loop instead of calculating math.factorial: should be more efficient for large numbers.

```
for ix in ar:
    if ix != 0:
        a = 1
        for el in range(order):
            a = a * (ix - el) 
        sum += a
```

Answer (score 0):

Not about Python particularly but true for any programming language. Calculating two factorials first and then dividing them is much [overcalculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine). Moreover it can easily lead to overflow in calculation even if the result itself is not an overflow. The overflow and the time consuming for calculating the intermediare results leads to failure of calculation, but sometimes it can be avoided. Let's do some pure math about operation fact (a) / fact(a-x).
The factorials

```
fact (a-x) =  1 * 2 * ... *(a-x)
fact (a)   =  1 * 2 * ...                                ... * a
           =  1 * 2 * ... *(a-x)  * ...                  ... * a
           = (1 * 2 * ... *(a-x)) * ((a-x+1) * (a-x+2) * ... * a)
           =  fact (a-x)          * ((a-x+1) * (a-x+2) * ... * a)
```

Division of factorials

```
fact (a) / fact(a-x)
     = fact (a-x) * ((a-x+1) * (a-x+2) * ... * a) / fact (a-x)
```

The common factor fact (a-x) cancels out
So, what remains is

```
fact (a) / fact(a-x) = (a-x+1) * (a-x+2) * ... * a
```

In other words is as simple as that:

```
fact (a) / fact (a-1)  = a
fact (a) / fact (a-2)  = a * (a-1)
...
```

Try calculate fact (1000) / fact (1000-2) by using naive and mathematical methods of calculation. The naive method in most programming languages will fail far before calculating fact(50), but you have to calculate two of them then divide.